# Update default PATH in CentOS6.6 Docker Image

Tags: centos6, docker

`docker run -t -i centos:6.6 /bin/bash`

I installed two java versions on this container Saved it via `docker commit blah blah` and I wanted to update the default PATH so when I run `docker run -t -i blah java -version` it will work. I tried it via /etc/defaults/java and roots bash_profile but no luck.

`docker run -t -i blah echo $PATH`

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin`

Comment: Exactly how did you install two java versions on this container?

Comment: from source into unique directories (/opt/java8:/opt/java7)  Need both versions.  I was hoping to add one of them.